# How to get the "oauth_token" for the authorize url in PIN-based OAuth flow for Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter

The logic looks circular to me(although I know I'm missing something)

I want to use this:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/pin-based-authorization

But in order to make the url to send the user to get the pin you need an "oauth_token" :

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/oauth/authorize

But to get the "oauth_token" you need a:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token

But that at the bottom shows it needs an "oauth_signature"

Well, an "oauth_signature" requires an "oauth_token" 
( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature ) which you don't have, making impossible to get an "oauth_token" because you need one to get one.

What am I missing here? I mainly just want to find out how to get that initial url for the PIN-based authorization, so I need that first "oauth_token" somehow.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types of oauth tokens - let's call them request tokens and normal tokens. Request tokens are used for the authentication, then once the authentication is done you get normal oauth tokens.

Calling `oauth/request_token` will generate a request token for you, which is a temporary token used for the actual authentication. Once that's done you have the normal tokens.

Comment: But look, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token , it requires a signature which in turn requires an "oauth_token" . https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

Comment: Yes, request_token requires an oauth_signature, but it does not require an oauth_token. It only requires that you identify the application (oauth_consumer_token), not the user.

Comment: Just so I understand completely: When I make the signature for the request token I don't need to include an oauth_token? But here ( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature ) it says "In the HTTP request the parameters are URL encoded, but you should collect the raw values. In addition to the request parameters, every oauth_* parameter needs to be included in the signature, so collect those too."

Comment: Look on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token at the bottom of the page for a sample OAuth signing process. You'll see that there's no oauth_token included and that the signing key is simply "consumersecret&" instead of "consumersecret&secret". When signing a request you only need to include the parameters you actually send to the server. If you don't send the server an oauth_token, there's no need to include it in the signature.

Comment: Look at the header you need to include: it includes a signature which needs an oauth_token

Comment: I definitely don't see an oauth_token in there - only the consumer token which you should already have (http://dev.twitter.com/apps). **A signature does not require an oauth_token.**

Comment: I just tried to obtain a request token without an oath_token: "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" was the server response. Do the nonce and timestamp of the signature have to match the nonce and timestamp of the request token request? The failure response seem to indicate it needs an oauth_token.

Comment: I really recommend that you use a library to take care of OAuth for you.

Answer (score 0):

set the callback URL both https://apps.twitter.com/ and in your code
. It is working for Me.

```
oauthCallback:@"myapp://twitter_access_tokens/"
```